# Yii, CJuiDatePicker how to show calendar for last 12 month ignore running(current) month

Tags: php, yii

For eg: If running month is march 2016 , than calendar need to display for jan2015 till feb 2016.

Thanks for help in advance.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'attribute' => 'submitDate',
                'model' => $model,
                'options' => array(
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
                    'showOn' => 'both',
                    'maxDate' => 0,
                    'buttonImage' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/img/icons/calendar_24.png',
                    'buttonImageOnly' => true,
                    'changeYear' => true,
                    'changeMonth' => false,

                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control timepicker-control',
                    'readonly' => true,
   ),
            ));
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `minDate` and `maxDate` as shown below to make it work.

```
<?php
$sd = date('01-m-Y', strtotime('-14 months'));
$ed = date('t-m-Y', strtotime('-1 months'));
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
        'attribute' => 'submitDate',
        'model' => $model,
        'options'=>array(                    
                'dateFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy',
                'showOn' => 'both',
                'buttonImage' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/img/icons/calendar_24.png',
                'buttonImageOnly' => true,
                'minDate'=>"$sd",
                'maxDate'=>"$ed",
                'changeYear' => true,
                'changeMonth' => false,
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'class' => 'form-control timepicker-control',
                'readonly' => true,
        ),
));
?>
```

It shown last 13 months as per your example of Jan'15 to Feb'16 but if you really need only last 12 months then change `-14 months` to `-13 months` for `$sd` (start date)